# Loop throw array, detect max value, and reset prev one

Tags: php, arrays

I would like someone to help me with this one, please.

I have this array.

```
foreach ($callersHistoryArray as $key => $value) {

    //check for duplicates and find the highest call duration
    if(in_array($value['caller'], $item, true) && $value['process'] == 0)
    {
        $duplicates = array(
            'key' => $key,
            'totalTime' => $callersHistoryArray[$key]['totalDurationTime']
        );

        echo print_r($duplicates, true);

        if ($duplicates['totalTime'] > $max) {
            $max = $duplicates['totalTime'];
            $value['unique'] = 1;
        }
    }
```

I loop throw `$callersHistoryArray` and detect duplicates, create a new array and find the max `totalTime` from them and set `unique` value to `1`.

When I go to second position in the `foreach`-loop, the previous one must change `unique` to `1`. But I can't do that. I used `prev($callersHistoryArray)`, to get last one but nothing.

Comment: You're creating a new `$duplicates` array each time round the loop. Are you sure that's what you mean to do? Maybe create it before the `foreach` loop then use `$duplicates[] = array()` to add a new entry to the dupes array. The loop through that at the end. Or if all you need to do is find the max time, ignore the dupes array and just check `$value['totalDurationTime']` instead. You could also set `$prevKey = $key` at the end of the loop to store the previous one if you need to access it.

Comment: like this:


$duplicates = array(
        'key' => '',
        'totalTime' => ''
    );

    foreach ($callersHistoryArray as $key => $value) {

        //check for duplicates and find the highest call duration
        if(in_array($value['caller'], $item, true) && $value['process'] == 0)
        {
            $duplicates[] = array($key, $callersHistoryArray[$key]['totalDurationTime']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question. I suspect you want to start with something like this:

```
<?php

$duplicates = array();
$maxTime = 0;
$unique = null;

foreach ($callersHistoryArray as $key => $value) {
    //check for duplicates and find the highest call duration
    if(in_array($value['caller'], $item, true) && $value['process'] == 0)
    {
        if ($maxTime < $value['totalDurationTime']) {
            $maxTime = $value['totalDurationTime'];
            $unique = $key;
        }
        $duplicates[] = $value;
    }
}

echo print_r($duplicates, true); // array of duplicates
echo print_r($callersHistoryArray[$unique], true); // item with highest time
```

Bugs notwithstanding, that should give you an array of the duplicates, and also tell you which item has the maximum duration. I don't know where `$item` comes from, so YMMV.

You might also need to handle two items having the same max duration.